# Gnome does not remember last file location if you untar a file

Tags: gnome, filesystem

If I download a packed file, and then want to open, the gnome file system points me to my home directory.
I want to go some other path, so I browse there and unpack it.

A moment later, another packed file download, and this time it points me to my home directory again, instead of the last location I unpacked the tar file.

Is it possible in gnome to make it remember the last location where you unpacked a file some moments ago?

Using ubuntu 10.04, fresh install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=160260) and [a patch submitted](http://bugzilla-attachments.gnome.org/attachment.cgi?id=124790), but unfortunately the patch has been sitting there idle for almost two years.

Comment: Thx for your answer.